# Better approach to close loans?

Tags: loans

If I have 3 loans is it better to pay them monthly and close after 3 years or close one at a time in one one year?

Comment: In general you pay them off the highest interest rate loan first, but you didn't give us many details to craft an answer. You might want to take a look at some of the other questions that discuss the best way to pay off multiple loans.

Answer (score 3):

It is typically best to pay minimum payments to 2 of the loans and pay aggressively on the third loan.

Some will tell you to pay the highest interest rate loan off first because "personal finance" is about "finance" and mathematically that saves you the most interest.

Some will tell you to pay the smallest balance loan off first because "personal finance" is "personal" and the psychological "win" of paying off a loan is more valuable than the small amount of interest difference between this strategy and paying off the loan with the highest interest rate first.

Comment: Nice wording of the alternatives.